# Battery Indicator shows wrong percentage

Tags: battery

Anyone have any idea what's going on with the percentage? (I *wish* my laptop was that awesome...)

[image]

Comment: Its based on current power usage, and sometimes its wrong with certain batteries.  I get similar results.

Comment: @The Evil Phoenix: Do you get the same results with Windows, or just Ubuntu? (I haven't tried it on this laptop since it's not really mine.)

Comment: I don't use Windows, but Windows' reports give me a 3 hour time frame when i only have approx. 30 minutes of power left, but sometimes the variations in time are narrowed down to brand of laptop... for instance my Dell Latitude shows the discrepant times for discharging, whereas my HP Mini 110 netbook is 99% accurate 99% of the time.

Comment: Do you mean estimated run time, or percentage?  Because you don't specify what you think is wrong with the shown percentage of 13.3, and what makes you think it is wrong.

Comment: @psusi: The 6 hours is correct, the 13% isn't.

Comment: @Mehrdad and you say this because?  Look at the battery properties and see what it says for the remaining capacity and total capacity.  The percentage should be the ratio between the two.

Comment: @psusi: I say this because I'd charged the battery right before, and it worked up to the ~6 hours. And because my battery sometimes goes **up** when I go to standby and come out. Or sometimes it shows that there's no battery in my computer. etc.

Comment: @Mehdrad, which version of Ubuntu is this? I found a [very similar Launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/583953) for 10.04 LTS and 10.10 that unfortunately seems to have expired.

Comment: @Warrioring64: It's indeed 10.04... seems to be exactly that bug.

Comment: @Mehdrad, personally I think it'd be best to re-report this bug (if somebody else hasn't already) on Launchpad, and provide your system specs when you do so. Hopefully you will have better luck and you can let the devs know that this is still a problem.

Comment: @Warrioring64: I could report it, but I wouldn't be able to help with any diagnostics tests that they may provide, because the laptop isn't mine. :\ Is it still worth a shot?

Comment: @Mehdrad, I would try it anyways in case somebody else with the same problem (like whoever reported the other bug) can come along and mark themselves as affected, along with their own specs. You may still want to ask your laptop's owner beforehand if they would grant you permission to gather any such information for this, however, or else just explain that specs are all you can provide on the bug report and your circumstances there.

Comment: This is a bug in 11.04 that I've been seeing for a while now... this occurs every time the computer comes off of sleep and keeps displaying the incorrect percentage remaining but will show the correct time remaining

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 3):

Try sudo powertop and see what that says...

Also, try letting the computer die while it is on battery power. That always updates my percentage.

Comment: `Also, try letting the computer die while it is on battery power`... you're joking, right? Isn't the whole point to know how much battery I have left *while it's > 0%*?

Comment: @Mehrdad: No, completely discharging a battery is a great way to recalibrate the meter.

Comment: Letting it die didn't work for me. I'm going to try charging it completely and letting it die again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that it shows the battery charge when full is much higher than the design charge. That cannot be. Hence the denominator increases and the percent becomes low.